# How to create select option using directives on button click in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to know how can i duplicate a select tag when i already render it using this lists..

```
var lists = [{name: "blue"},{name: "green"},{name: "red"},{name: "yellow"}]
```

and there is a add button to duplicate this select tags.

I created fiddle for this:
http://jsfiddle.net/rdy4e4xx/

I am thinking to used directives for this but i dont know where to start. Thanks guys.

Comment: `dynamic select options from this lists of objects` this part is not clear.

Comment: i edited my question already, what i want is to duplicate the first rendered select tags from that lists... so i will have, 2 select tags using the object lits, when the user click the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this (**Updated**):

HTML:

```
  <div ng-controller="ListsCtrl">
        {{ mySizes }}
        <select ng-model="selectTag.value"  ng-repeat="selectTag in selectTags">
            <option value="">- - Make Selection - -</option>
            <option ng-repeat="size in sizes" value="{{ size.name }}">{{ size.name}}</option>
        </select>
      <button type="button" ng-click="duplicateSelectTag()">Duplicate Select Tags</button>
      Selected values:
      <ul ng-repeat="selectTag in selectTags">
          <li>{{selectTag.value}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller('ListsCtrl',function($scope){
   $scope.sizes = [{name: "blue"},{name: "green"},{name: "red"},{name: "yellow"}]; 
    $scope.selectTags=[{
        value:null
    }];
    $scope.duplicateSelectTag = function() {

        $scope.selectTags.push({});
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rdy4e4xx/6/)

Comment: No, not like this..

its something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/rdy4e4xx/3/

when a user click the button it will duplicate the select tags using angularjs

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicate the select tags"? Add more "select" controls to the page?

Comment: check this one: http://jsfiddle.net/rdy4e4xx/4/
the select tag is duplicated.. whenever i click the add "duplicate select tags" button i want to create new select tag lists..

Comment: And then, you probably want to collect values to some structure:
http://jsfiddle.net/rdy4e4xx/6/

Comment: Whoa.. this one is good.. is it possible to distinguish every newly created select?.. example the first select create has a name of: selection1, then the next created to selection2.

Comment: If I got you right, then you are looking for this one:
http://jsfiddle.net/rdy4e4xx/7/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

```
  <div ng-controller="ListsCtrl">
        {{ mySizes }}
        <select ng-model="mySizes">
            <option value="">- - Make Selection - -</option>
            <option ng-repeat="size in sizes" value="{{ size.name }}">{{ size.name}}</option>
        </select>

     <button ng-click="dupplicate(mySizes)">Duplicate Select Tags</button>
  </div>

var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller('ListsCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.sizes = [{name: "blue"},{name: "green"},{name: "red"},{name: "yellow"}]; 
    $scope.dupplicate = function(mySizes){       
        $scope.sizes.push({name: mySizes});
    };
});
```